# drupal 6 using form api number field

Tags: hooks

Currently i am  using drupal six form api. I just wanted to add number field to form but there is no way that i found to add numeric field to form. Is there is any way to do this by using form api drupal6 to add numeric field in drupal 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Elements](https://drupal.org/project/elements) module provides an HTML5 number field element to the FAPI. You can use it like this:

```
$form['foo'] = array(
  'type' => 'numberfield'.
  'title' => t('Bar'),
  ...
);
```